# why is this simple fiddle not working

Tags: javascript, html

This fiddle is not working-

http://jsfiddle.net/RcfNL/1/

I just want to add a `text field` in a `div` `onchange` in `drop down`. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your code in a [document ready function](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   ...
});
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/RcfNL/2/).

> A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

Comment: @halkujabra I've added a quote from the linked article in my answer.

Comment: @halkujabra This is one of the first things you should learn when using jQuery. I'm sure all the tutorials mention it.

Answer (score 2):

You can also alternatively change the options in the `Frameworks and Extensions` to `onLoad` options so it waits the entire DOM to be ready.Check Your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RcfNL/3/)

Comment: That's true for the fiddle, but when he later tries to move the code to his own page it doesn't help.